# `phd` unable to switch to the correct user with `sudo`

Tags: ubuntu, phabricator

I'm very new in installing phabricator and I'm having a problem running the daemon.
When I run `sudo ./bin/phd start` I receive this error.

```
Usage Exception: Daemons are configured to run as user "phd" in      
configuration option `phd.user`, but the current user is "root" and `phd`
was unable to switch to the correct user with `sudo`. Command output:

Command failed with error #255!
COMMAND
exec sudo -En -u 'phd' -- ./phd-daemon 

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
[2016-04-23 18:50:09] EXCEPTION: (Exception) Specified daemon PID directory
('/var/tmp/phd/pid') does not exist or is not writable by the daemon user!
at [<phutil>/src/daemon/PhutilDaemonOverseer.php:114]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=a2ab38df78a9), phabricator(head=master,
ref.master=00885edc47d4), phutil(head=master, ref.master=b8058f6e29ba)
#0 PhutilDaemonOverseer::__construct(array) called at 
[<phabricator>/scripts/daemon/launch_daemon.php:11]
```

I'm following this installation guide. https://gist.github.com/sparrc/b4eff48a3e7af8411fc1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a phd user created on the machine?
If you don't, create it.

If you do, try switching to phd first or run the command with `sudo -u phd` prepended to the command.